# fluent map a text array, string [ x ]

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

This is driving me somewhat crazy. I can simply not find anywhere on the web exactly how to map an object that holds an array.

I have an object that holds an array of strings, string[X]. X can vary.
I want the customsqltype "Text".

Exactly how do I write this? 
Apparently nhibernate needs an index, I want to use the index of the array for each string.

Thanks!

Comment: Add a tag for the desired language.

Comment: The way to do this in the database I'd want a reference to the table holding the list, a column for index and a column for the actual value. Could have a fourth column as the first column, for individual Id or a combined id of index and reference.

Comment: This is the closest I've come to what I have been looking for. 

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/association-mapping.aspx?display=Print

Comment: I can not answer my own question.

Comment: try again in a few days.

Comment: Does it have to be an array?  FNH will let you map IList<string> - either map-by-code or automap (my preference).  Also, I upvoted your question - that should put you over the 50 point line, which will give you more privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I've come to what I have been looking for.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/association-mapping.aspx?display=Print

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Your-very-first-NHibernate-application-Part-2.aspx

Comment: To anyone still looking, these links listed above are no longer good.